# click event not being fired when parent element prevents bubbling

Tags: javascript, event-handling, cross-browser, nested, event-bubbling

I've tested in a few modern browsers with inconsistent results. I'm sure it has something to do with capturing vs bubbling event support differences. I've setup a test environment to replicate the issue here: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=J7HjnWJP) and use [this service](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) to run a live preview.

The problem is this: Some browsers will ignore the anchor href click event when an ancestor prevents bubbling. It doesn't make sense because the middle element will fire its event before it bubbles down but the anchor element will not. Why does a javascript click event work but the href event will not?

Here are my results when "click me" is pressed:

**Chrome 9.0.597.98**: href is ignored + inner and outter is printed

**IE 8.0.6001.19019**: href works + inner and outter is printed

**Firefox 3.6.13**: href is ignored + inner and outter is printed

So my ultimate question is: How do I get href to work cross-browser when an ancestor element is preventing event bubble? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I would just like to note that the discussion continues in Pointy's comments and I would also like to thank him for his tremendous help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it's not

```
event.returnResult = false;
```

in IE, it's:

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

The link makes it through in IE because you're not correctly telling the browser not to take the default action.

If you *want* the default action to take place, then don't call ".preventDefault()" and don't set "returnValue" to `false`.

Comment: Ack! Thanks for your reply and you're right, it is returnValue. Not sure how I missed this.

Comment: I still hoped someone to come by with an actual solution.

Comment: An "actual solution" to what problem?

Comment: What confuses me is this: why does propagation act as expected but preventDefault does not? Propagation fires each event while bubbling up until it reaches the top unless instructed otherwise. If I apply preventDefault to a parent element, why does it prevent default action on all its children elements as well?

Comment: The default action for an event only matters for the **target** element. What would the default action for "click" be on a parent `<div>` anyway?

Comment: Here is a very similar setup I'm using on a current project: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=g6nbyQip preventDefault is applied to the span element but the anchor element inside inherits it as well. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Basically I need to outer anchor to be ignored but the inner anchor to work as expected. Is this possible?

Comment: Putting anchors inside other anchors is invalid HTML.

Comment: Yes I know. The project has to be flexible and in some rare cases I may have to deal with this. I'm not certain but I don't believe invalid HTML would cause this behavior.

Comment: Well, the browsers can respond to invalid markup any way they want to, so if things are not consistent it won't do much good to complain. (Not that it does much good to complain anyway :-)  As I understand it, however, the "default" action for an event is the action related to the original event target. Bubbling up through an element that has its own default action for an event does not trigger the action there.

Comment: Invalid markup aside (because I don't think that is the issue) here is a valid markup that demonstrates the issue I am having: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5NWfMQCc please notice the anchor click event works but href does not?

Comment: I can't tell from just that URL you posted - can you post the whole thing, or set it up on a better site like jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Looking at that code, it's really the same thing.  The event handler on the `<div>` calls "preventDefault()" on the event object. You should understand that the event object passed to the handlers is the same for all of them - in other words, there is **just one event object** and it's passed to the handlers for each container element walking up the DOM.  If *any* of the handlers call "preventDefault()" (or set "returnValue" to `false` for IE), then the default action will not be performed.

Comment: OK, that's easier to understand :-)  Well, as I wrote, the thing is that your code is still setting "returnValue" to `false` on the event object. There is only one event object made for any single "click" that happens, and the same object is passed to all the event handlers as it bubbles up.  If *any* handler sets "returnValue" to `false`, then the default operation won't happen.

Comment: Ok I kind of that that was the case. Just to clarify: the event gets captured on the target (in this case the anchor) and does not fire until it finishes walking the dom? preventDefault and stopPropagation must behave differently because an event set on the target gets fired right away and then continues walking the dom correct?

Comment: Yes that's right - "stopPropagation" makes the bubbling process stop, and if the default has not been prevented it will happen immediately after the handler exits.

Comment: ahhh.. did not know that. thanks a lot for you quick responses. very much appreciated!